# How do I sync a Maschine instance on mac to a Maschine instance on pc?

Tags: midi, mac, pc

My electronic group has been primarily an in-studio recording band, but are to the point where we need to take things live.  Not really sure how to go about getting things going. One of the guys uses a Maschine MK1 on his Dell PC.  I have a macbook pro and am about to purchase a Maschine Mk1 myself, but I want to make sure we will be able to sync up before buying..  We don't use abelton or anything like that, we just want to be able to jam together and trigger samples with everything sounding good and in sync.  any suggestions?

Comment: This is a sound design and sound production oriented site.  Not a musician site.  This question appears that it is probably off topic.

Comment: This may or may not be on topic over on Music.SE - I'll migrate it over and we can see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You will need to set one device to send midi clock and the other to receive midi clock. Then attach via the appropriate "out to in" sockets with one midi cable.

I found this information on page 49 and 50 of Maschine manual v1.5.